# In pytest, when using 'usefixtures', are the fixtures executed in order?

Tags: pytest, fixture

For example, if I have:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("fixture1", "fixture2", "fixture3")
class TestFunction:
    .........
```

Let's say fixture1, fixture2 and fixture3 are independent class level fixtures.
Is it true that the execution order is always 1->2->3 during setup and 3->2->1 during teardown?

If not, is there a way to enforce it?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to enforce it, why not make fixtures dependent on each other?

Comment: @compiler The reason is that then there is no way to select different fixtures for different classes. I just didn't get the point that if I need to make them dependent on each other, why don't I just make them as one fixture?